# OpenCL - write_imagef Compilation failure : CL_INVALID_VALUE

Tags: opencl

If I run the code below (OpenCL C 1.1, JavaCL RC3) I got error

```
Compilation failure : CL_INVALID_VALUE
```

The strength thing about the code is that after replacing the line:

```
    write_imagef(output, (int2)(coords.y,coords.x), rnd);
```

with

```
    write_imagef(output, (int2)(coords.y,coords.x), pixel);
```

works perfectly. **How can I initialize float4 struct correctly and assign a value to the output image?**

```
__kernel void rotate_image(
    __read_only image2d_t input,
    __write_only image2d_t output,
    sampler_t sampler,
    int hiddenLayerX,
    int hiddenLayerY
    )
{
     // Store each work-items unique row and column
    int2 coords = (int2){get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1)};
    float4 pixel = read_imagef(input, sampler, coords);
    float4 rnd =  (float4){1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f};
    write_imagef(output, (int2)(coords.y,coords.x), rnd);    
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure: Is the output image in the right format? Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score -1):

These are different ways of initializing:

```
float4 val =  (float4)(1.0f); //Extends the single value to the float4
float4 val =  (float4)(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f); //Set every value
float4 val =  (float4)(my_float2, my_float2); //Copy from another component(s)
float4 val =  (float4)(my_float2, 1.0f, 1.0f); //Many ways
float4 val =  (float4)(1.0f, my_float3); //Many more ways
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately none of the initialization methods has solved my problem. After running the code with any combination of the initializations, I got "Compilation failure : CL_INVALID_VALUE" error. If I use "pixel" (float4) instead of "rnd" (float4) in the write_imagef, everything is OK.